# Computer based examination Application to be run on net wrok

Tags: vb.net

I have developed a Computer Based Examination application.  I have designed the application so that when initialized by admin. client computers could take exam with their logins.  **I am using SQL Server Compact Edition.**
I tested it with a small network (shared computers through a hub)  It works well.

I am not so good at networking things.  Can I used the same way when the client computers are more than 50?
Is there any better alternative?

Thanks
Furqan